# How to make IWebBrowser2->Navigate use a proxy server

Tags: proxy, iwebbrowser2

I have some code (VC++) that gets an IWebBrowser2 and uses it to navigate to some URL.   I want it to go via a proxy server.  I've tried a few solutions posted around but none seem to work.

The nearest I got was using MSDN code but that actually altered Internet Explorer's settings so that the change was system wide - this is not practical for my needs.

Ideally, I'd like the proxy setting to be on a per IWebBrowser2 instance - so I could have 2 IWebBrowser2 objects in my code, one using a proxy, the other not.  If that's not possible, then per process is workable.

If someone has this working and could post some code I'd be very grateful.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: nobody knows how to do that?